# In the website, the article time crawling by using Beautifulsoup is not working

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

My project aims that all web-article information was crawled by pages using the Beautifulsoup function.
The article information is the article title, time, body.
But, the article time text is behind

tag as you can see.
I tried to do my best all day. However, I can not solve the problem.
How to solve this problem?

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import requests
i = input('Start page? : ')
k = input('End page? : ')

pagenum = int(i)
lastpage = int(k)
count = int(i)

news_info = pd.DataFrame(columns=('Title', 'Datetime', 'Article'))

idx = 0

while pagenum<lastpage + 1:
  url = f'http://www.koscaj.com/news/articleList.html?page={pagenum}&total=72698&box_idxno=&sc_section_code=S1N2&view_type=sm'
  html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
  soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
  links = soup.find_all(class_='list-titles')

  print(f'-----{count}page result-----')
  for link in links:
    news_url = "http://www.koscaj.com"+link.find('a')['href']
    news_link = urllib.request.urlopen(news_url).read()
    soup2 = BeautifulSoup(news_link, 'html.parser')

    title = soup2.find('div', {'class':'article-head-title'})
    date = soup2.find('div',{'class':'info-text'})
    datetime = date[1]
    article = soup2.find('div', {'id':'article-view-content-div'})

    news_info.loc[idx] = [title, datetime, article]
    idx += 1
 
  pagenum += 1
  count += 1

print('Complete')
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. What *exactly* is the problem? What issues do you have? Any errors?

Answer (score 1):

ya it's not clear what you're issue is. I am assuming you are after this. Also note you need to grab the text of the title and articles as well (as you are not doing that in your code):

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import requests
i = input('Start page? : ')
k = input('End page? : ')

pagenum = int(i)
lastpage = int(k)
count = int(i)

news_info = pd.DataFrame(columns=('Title', 'Datetime', 'Article'))

idx = 0

while pagenum<lastpage + 1:
  url = f'http://www.koscaj.com/news/articleList.html?page={pagenum}&total=72698&box_idxno=&sc_section_code=S1N2&view_type=sm'
  html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
  soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
  links = soup.find_all(class_='list-titles')

  print(f'-----{count}page result-----')
  for link in links:
    news_url = "http://www.koscaj.com"+link.find('a')['href']
    news_link = urllib.request.urlopen(news_url).read()
    soup2 = BeautifulSoup(news_link, 'html.parser')

    title = soup2.find('div', {'class':'article-head-title'})
    if title:
        title = soup2.find('div', {'class':'article-head-title'}).text
    else:
        title = ''
    date = soup2.find('div',{'class':'info-text'})
    
    try:
        datetime = date.find('i', {'class':'fa fa-clock-o fa-fw'}).parent.text.strip()
    except:
        datetime = ''
    
    article = soup2.find('div', {'id':'article-view-content-div'})
    if article:
        article = soup2.find('div', {'id':'article-view-content-div'}).text
    else:
        article = ''

    news_info.loc[idx] = [title, datetime, article]
    idx += 1
 
  pagenum += 1
  count += 1

print('Complete')
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I solved the problem. I am a beginner in Python. Now, I am studying Python reading books. It is lucky for me to find this site!

Answer (score 0):

You have to access inner children in this tag.

Assuming that variable `date` contains:

```
<div class="info-text">
<ul class="...">
<li><i class="fa fa-user-o fa-fw"></i> 전문건설신문</li>
<li><i class="fa fa-clock-o fa-fw"></i> 승인 2020.11.25 18:24</li>
...
```

You can access date with:

`date.find_all('li')[1].text`

Which will be:

`승인 2020.11.25 18:24`

You can read more about accessing children in [docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#going-down).